# pymssql 1.9.908 error when querying

Tags: python, pymssql

I am having problems in using pymssql 1.9.908 on my windows 2k3 x64.
    I used the below codes to test a simple query. However I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    cur.execute('SELECT * from tbl_staticDetails')
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 296, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:3246)
OperationalError: SQL Server message 4004, severity 16, state 1, line 1:
Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC version 3.7 or earlier.
DB-Lib error message 4004, severity 16:
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server
```

Here's my sample code inputted in IDLE:

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='<IP reachable by my machine>', user='sa', password='<password>', database='<database nbame>')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('SELECT * from tbl_staticDetails')
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/faq.php:

> In SQL 2000 SP4 or newer, SQL 2005 or SQL 2008, if you do a query that
>   returns NTEXT type data, you may encounter the following exception:
>   _mssql.MssqlDatabaseError: SQL Server message 4004, severity 16, state 1, line 1: Unicode data in a Unicode-only collation or ntext data
>   cannot be sent to clients using DB-Library (such as ISQL) or ODBC
>   version 3.7 or earlier.
>
> It means that SQL Server is unable to send Unicode data to pymssql,
>   because of shortcomings of DB-Library for C. You have to CAST or
>   CONVERT the data to equivalent NVARCHAR data type, which does not
>   exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: so can I just make the datatype of the field in my table CHAR and it will work? Thank you